# Difference between puts a and puts "#{a}"

Tags: ruby

I thought that doing `puts #{a}` would result in the same output as `puts a`, but found this not to be the case.  Consider:

```
irb(main):001:0> a = [1,2]
=> [1, 2]
irb(main):002:0> puts a
1
2
=> nil
irb(main):003:0> puts "#{a}"
12
=> nil
irb(main):004:0>
```

In the above example it doesn't matter much, but it may matter when I want to print multiple variables on one line, such as (psudocode):

```
puts "There are #{a.size} items in the whitelist: #{a}"
```

Why is the output different here?  Do they actually do different things, or have different semantics?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `"#{a}"` calls the `#to_s` method on the expression.

So:

```
puts a        # equivalent to, well, puts a
puts "#{a}"   # equivalent to the next line
puts a.to_s
```

*Update:*

To elaborate, `puts` eventually calls `#to_s` but it adds logic in front of the actual output, including special handling for arrays. It just happens that `Array#to_s` doesn't use the same algorithm. [(See `puts` docs here.)](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-puts) Here is exactly what it does...

```
rb_io_puts(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE out)
{
    int i;
    VALUE line;

    /* if no argument given, print newline. */
    if (argc == 0) {
        rb_io_write(out, rb_default_rs);
        return Qnil;
    }
    for (i=0; i<argc; i++) {
        if (TYPE(argv[i]) == T_STRING) {
            line = argv[i];
            goto string;
        }
        line = rb_check_array_type(argv[i]);
        if (!NIL_P(line)) {
            rb_exec_recursive(io_puts_ary, line, out);
            continue;
        }
        line = rb_obj_as_string(argv[i]);
      string:
        rb_io_write(out, line);
        if (RSTRING_LEN(line) == 0 ||
            !str_end_with_asciichar(line, '\n')) {
            rb_io_write(out, rb_default_rs);
        }
    }

    return Qnil;
}
```

Comment: Your edit effectively answered my last question, but raised another.  If `puts a` doesn't call `to_s`, then how does it print the values of `a` to the console?  Perhaps this is not answerable here, or maybe I'm thinking too much like a C++ guy...

Comment: @JohnDibling [puts doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-puts) - in case of arrays it doesn't.

Comment: I see what you're syaing, but it must at some point (perhaps deep in the bowels of Ruby) convert the integer value `1` to the string representation of that integer.  What I'm really wondering is how that's done.